# plotly indicator and bar plot behave differently in mobile mode flexdashboard R

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am building a flexdashboard and want to include several plotly indicator and bar plots. In desktop mode everything is fine, however, when I switch to mobile mode, the indicator chart gets completely downsized, whereas the bar plot stays in an acceptable size. I´ve tried serveral ways to change that behavior for the indicator chart, no success until now. Can you help me please?

Here is screenshot of the unintended behavior:

[screenshot in mobile mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZVN4.png)

I tried to manipulated the behavior in plot building, via css, etc. No success until now...

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? What does your YAML specify? What does the *not* mobile version look like? What were you expecting the mobile version to look like?